Form Field Type to browse and select a file
I'm struggling with finding a good way to have a control (or controls) on a form which allow the user to browse and select a file in a folder tree.
There may be several thousand files in several hundred folders (nested up to 4 levels deep).
The best I can do is use the folderlist field (with recursive="true") and a separate filelist field (which only shows files in a single folder) but this is not very nice - when the folder selection changes it has to submit the form to refresh the filelist, and the user has to separately open the filelist to see the files in the folder.
What I am after is something like a file browser - surely it must be possible to do this? It is surprising that it is not a standard form field type. I don't mind having to make a custom field type but I'm not sure how to get the best user interaction experience.
Maybe there is something out there I haven't found... any help or suggestions please.
(J5 by the way)

Have you tried Media field?

Yes but Media field is limited (sensibly) to sub-directories on /images  I'm wanting to be able to list folders and files anywhere in the webspace, or indeed anywhere on the server if the permissions are ok.

For now what I have is a custom child of folderlist which works from any directory and is modified to improve the display (indenting subfolders rather than listing the whole path which onchange feeds a separate filelist for the selected folder.
I work ok, but a single filemnager display type display to select from would be better (and save a call back to the server to refresh the filelist field)
